# how to examine contents of database during or after rails integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, integration, examine

I'm a fairly experienced dev but I'm a total web and rails newbie. I'm trying to implement a kind of market place rails application. I've developed the app to where I'm far along in the customer interaction flow and now I'm realizing I need to automate stuff cause dev/test via browser consumes so much time.

Say I have customer interaction flow that goes from page A, then to page B, C, D...G. And now I'm developing the 'H' page. I know I could use the automated test facilities (e.g. Minitest) to automate the whole thing. But being as how I still have my rails training wheels on sometimes I like to see database state progress from one state to the next for myself rather than just trust that the test automation really is doing what I'm expecting.

My question is, is there a way to have Minitest automate/simulate the user interaction flow from A -> G and then let me take over in a manual way from there such that I could click my newly-developed browser button while using my db browser to watch db state progress appropriately?

If not - which is what I'm guessing - I'd happily settle for a way to examine the database contents after an integration test. My integration tests work just fine. It's just that after they complete I'd like to be able to pop open my db browser and poke around, verifying various values to ensure to my satisfaction things in the db are as they should be.

Another possible solution that would work for me is if there was something within my integration tests that could access db values so I could verify things programmatically. I have in mind something like how [assigns give you access to instance variables within your integration tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse) that you can then do 'asserts' calls on.

And, of course, please let me know if I'm way off track and there's a "best practice" for this type of thing that I've missed.

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.2p95

Comment: You can use Capybara with minitest to simulate the user interaction in an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

While Minitest doesn't have a way to do the first option you mentioned, you might checkout [Watir](http://watir.com/) as a means of (partially) automating tests so you leave off at a certain point with the browser still open and continue manually while watching what's going on in the DB.

However, since the second option you mentioned is possible with Minitest (and will save you even more time by being fully automated) I'd highly recommend it. See the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page) for some examples (you might find the whole thing helpful, but here's a section that shows a test much like what you are looking for: [Section 7.4.4](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-a_test_for_valid_submission).)